# I am trying to read files and make a scatterplot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a scatterplot based on 2 files. In both files, there are `(x,y)` values listed out like this:

```
x1,   y1
x2,   y2
x200, y200
```

My job is to read both of them and create a scatterplot based on those `(x,y)` values. I can't use numpy or any other software except for matplotlib. How would I go about doing this?

How do I tell it that the files are in `(x,y)` format and the first value should be `x` and 2nd should be `y` to plot it?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? You should look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

Comment: I don't think you can use matplotlib without numpy

Answer (score 0):

Have you parsed your results?

data.split(',') will return a list with all the values (you might need to split twice, I'm not sure if there's a space between y(n) and x(n+1) or a comma).
once you have all the results you can simply plot out the dots without any trouble.